# Using replace function in GNU CLISP 2.49

Tags: replace, common-lisp

I have seen examples online and try to use it in my code but I find this is really weird. When I execute

```
(replace "abcdef" "54321" :start1 2 :end1 5 :start2 0 :end2 2)
```

in GUN CLisp 2.49 it gives what I want,

```
"ab543f"
```

but when I write the exactly the same code in a text editor, and load the file, it doesn't work.

```
attempt to modify a read-only string: "abcdef"
```

I want to write a function that read a list of numbers and replace the first number in that string with its negative value.

Is it possible to write a function like:

```
(defun rep4negative (readlist)
       (let ((no (car readlist))
             (negativeNo (- 0 no)))

             (replace readlist "negativeNo" ))
```

and this function will return the new readlist, for example

```
(rep4negative '5 1 2)→(-5 1 2)
```

Comment: Please fix code formatting (you can use Emacs to do that for you)

Comment: what does `return (new)readlist`  mean? what is `cad`?

Comment: Please copy an paste all commands you issue and all errors you get; please also supply the inputs and outputs you want to get.

Comment: "when I write the exactly the same code in a text editor, and load the file, it doesn't work." What does this mean?  If you don't tell us what actually happened, we have no way too know. Did you get an error? Did it run, but with a different output than what you'd expected?  Something else?

Answer (score 3):

I think you've got your terminology a bit confused. In particular, you've written that you want to read a list of numbers (fine) and then replace the first number in the string. Hmm. Assuming you meant "list" there, I think you want a transformation that looks like this:

```
(1 2 3) => (-1 2 3)
(10)    => (-10)
()      => ()
```

You can write that with something like the following:

```
(defun negate-first (list)
    (when list
        (cons (- (car list)) (cdr list))))
```

Here it is in action:

```
[2]> (negate-first '(1 2 3 4))
(-1 2 3 4)
[3]> (negate-first '(10))
(-10)
[4]> (negate-first '())
NIL
```

Alternatively, maybe you want to replace all occurrences of the first number with its negation, so you'd get

```
(1 2 3 1) => (-1 2 3 -1)
```

and so on. To do that, you could use code like this:

```
(defun negate-first-throughout (list)
    (when list
        (substitute (- (car list)) (car list) list)))
```

Trying it out:

```
[2]> (negate-first-throughout '(1 2 3 1))
(-1 2 3 -1)
[3]> (negate-first-throughout '(1))
(-1)
[4]> (negate-first-throughout '())
NIL
```

If you didn't mean either of those two things, maybe you need to be clearer in your question...

**EDIT**

In the first comment below (with the obvious missing closing parens added), you say you want

```
((1 (2 1)) (2 (2 3)) (4 (4 3))) => ((-1 (2 1)) (-2 (2 3)) (-4 (4 3)))
```

You can either map `#'negate-first` from above over your list or write it all in one as follows:

```
(defun negate-cars (lists)
  (mapcar (lambda (sublist)
            (cons (- (car sublist)) (cdr sublist)))
          lists))
```

Testing:

```
[1]> (defun negate-cars (lists)
      (mapcar (lambda (sublist)
                (cons (- (car sublist)) (cdr sublist)))
              lists))
NEGATE-CARS
[2]> (negate-cars '((1 (2 1)) (2 (2 3)) (4 (4 3))))
((-1 (2 1)) (-2 (2 3)) (-4 (4 3)))
```

Comment: what if I want to change `((1 (2 1) (2 (2 3)) (4 (4 3)))→((-1 (2 1) (-2 (2 3)) (-4 (4 3)))`  which is a list with sub list and every first, second, third ...'s first term  is replaced with its negation. I know `(car list)` will get its first in the list, but what about the followings? if i don't know the length of the list. p.s. sorry for the bad  terminology.

Answer (score 1):

## 1

`Replace` *destructively* modifies its first argument.

Modifying a literal has undefined consequences.  You are trying to modify a string literal.

In most typical use cases, you will not use literal strings but strings generated or input.

You can repair your example by copying the literal first.

```
(replace (copy-seq "abcdef") "54321" :start1 2 :end1 5 :start2 0 :end2 2)
```

## 2

Do it step by step at first.

```
(defun negate-first (list)
  (let ((first (first list))  ; get the first element
        (rest (rest list)))   ; the rest will be unmodified
    (cons (- first) rest)))   ; put the negative first before the rest
```

You might soon do this in your head, so you do not need to assign intermediate variables.  Then you arrive at this shorter code:

```
(defun negate-first (list)
  (cons (- (first list)) (rest list)))
```